# GlassFish: Deploy w/ --force

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-3, asadmin

When I attempt to deploy a war usig the --force option, it works, but I get this response:

```
Deprecated syntax, instead use:
asadmin --passwordfile password --host localhost --user admin deploy [options] ...
```

When using the newer syntax, how do I still specify the --force option? Adding anything other than the .war file after "deploy" results in this message:

```
Command deploy only accepts one operand
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quick answer: Move the --force after the "deploy" command:

*asadmin --passwordfile password --host localhost --user admin deploy **--force** myapp.war*

Here's a step-by-step explanation. First, the asadmin command line format:

*asadmin [asadmin options] command [command options].*

First, specify the asadmin options:

*asadmin **--passwordfile password --user admin --host localhost** command [command options]*

Next, specify the command you are interested in:

*asadmin --passwordfile password --user admin --host localhost **deploy** [command options]*

Next, specify command options.

*asadmin --passwordfile password --host localhost --user admin deploy **--force** myapp.war*

Comment: I attempted this very structure when attempting to execute it from an ANT build script. I will try via the command line directly to ensure it wasn't an issue on the ANT side of the equation...