# Configuration of authentication for deploy in GlassFish

Tags: deployment, ejb-3.0, glassfish-3

I'm studyng the EJB 3 with the Oracle's [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/docinfo.html), Ant 1.8 and Glassfish 3.1.2.2 (in Windows 7).

In the first [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbod.html) I build correctly the EAR, but when I run

```
ant deploy
```

by cmd, I receive this message

```
deploy:
     [echo] deploys the application in cart -  build/cart.ear
     [echo] C:\installati\glassfish-3_1_2_2\glassfish3\glassfish/bin/asadmin.bat
        --host localhost       --port 4848       deploy --name cart       --forc
e=true --upload=true        --dbvendorname SQL92 build/cart.ear
     [exec] Authentication failed for user: null
     [exec] (Usually, this means invalid user name and/or password)
     [exec] Command deploy failed.
```

The tutorial doesn't say anything about security configurations and I don't know very well Glassfish.
I tried to use the command *add-resources* (following this similar [thread](http://glassfish.10926.n7.nabble.com/quot-Authentication-failed-with-password-quot-updating-asadminpass-td75950.html)) but I don't know the syntax of this file.

I don't think there's a problem about configuration of path, because the bat are correctly runned...

I see the answer to [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385079/glassfish-deploy-w-force), but it's not my situation...

Has someone found sometime a similar problem?

Comment: Did you try right-click -> Deploy in NetBeans?

Comment: I'm working with Eclipse: I use cmd+ANT for have the basic proces of developmetn/deploy

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved: I'm re-installed Glassfish.

After the reinstallation, most of examples (not all) are working correctly ***without authentication hypothesis***.

Maybe my problem was born using a solution found in the web for another problem, and    unperceively I had misdirect something in deploy's process of GlasshFish.